# how do you sort an array with different elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to sort the following array by the items name (the second element) how do I do this?  I am stuck.

```
    items[0] = new Product("001","Glue sticks",6,.06);
    items[1] = new Product("002","Six inch rulers",25,.59);
    items[2] = new Product("003","Paper-ream",5,6.99);
    items[3] = new Product("004","Black ink pens",15,.97);
    items[4] = new Product("005","No. 2 pencils",20,.30);
```

Comment: Let's start from a basic question: how do you compare two Product objects? How do you know which is "greater" than the other?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Comparator

```
Arrays.sort(items, new Comparator<Product>()
{
    @Override public int compare(final Product p1, Product p2)
    {
        // TODO check for null object
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am new to programming.  Do I need to initialize p1 and p2?

Comment: I went back into my code and put it in a different spot and it worked.  Thank you sooooo much.  I have been stuck at this point too long.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is better you use from arraylist and arraylist.sort() method